# language in codeigniter doesn' t work as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a web site with two languages, it works in localhost perfect. but when I run it on a production enviroment and people try to change the language doesn't work, they need to press F5 key in the browser,so then the site reload in the language they choose. Any idea?? Thanks...

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();     
        $this->lang->load('navmenu', $this->session->userdata('language'));
        $this->lang->load('search', $this->session->userdata('language'));
        $this->lang->load('home', $this->session->userdata('language'));
    }

/.../
function ChangeLanguage ($lang)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('language', $lang);
        redirect(base_url());
    }

  anchor('lang/changelanguage/spanish','Espa&ntilde;ol')  
   anchor('lang/changelanguage/english','English')
```

Comment: How are they changing the language?  Looking at the controller you've shown, they'd need to re-load, yes.  The PHP needs to read the new session data and deliver the new content.

Comment: ...and what does the `changelanguage` function do?  I assume it sets the session and then redirects?

Comment: exacly, that's what changelanguage do. Set the language in the session, and then I load it in the contructor of the controller class

Comment: Try making the redirect like this `redirect('/','refresh');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to debug this in production server, you can temporary put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and see what other errors are there that prevents the proper redirecting.
You also should check the response headers being sent by your production server.
Does it have "cache", does it need re-validate header, etc